# android onclick () not responding

Tags: java, android

I am new to android programming and trying to develop TIC TAC TOE game. I have created gameLogic() method and the problem is this that it is not working as it is expected to do, means on click of ImageView none of the images is getting displayed. Any help will be highly appreciated.

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void gameLogic(View view) {
        ImageView tappedView = (ImageView)view;
        tappedView.setTranslationY(-3000f);
        tappedView.setImageResource(R.drawable.black);
        tappedView.animate().translationYBy(3000f).setDuration(500);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you set `onClickListener` for the `ImageView`?

Comment: where is onClick?

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onClick (View view) { 
ImageView tappedView = (ImageView)view;
tappedView.setTranslationY(-3000f);
tappedView.setImageResource(R.drawable.black); 
tappedView.animate().translationYBy(3000f).setDuration(500)
```

Try changing the class name to `onClick` and go to XML the page where you designs the button and declare `onClick` method in the image view button.

All you have to do is let the design page know where the code is by providing a common name to look for which is on click.
Also you have to add an `onClick` listener which listens for the button to click as the code should know which button it is linked to.
So declare a setonclicklistener method on the button Id and you're set to go.
Also write the code within the override after the setting of the layout.

Hope you understood :)

If you're new try head first Android it'll be really helpful I know how struggling it is during the initial days.